# my IP is deallocated by itself after a time later

Tags: linux, networking

I use ssh to connect a remote Linux device and assign IP address manually by `ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2` (I know ifconfig is depreciated and I should use ip instead). More or less each half an hour or so, the IP is deallocated and cause interruption to my remote connection. It happens even I assign the IP address by `ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0`. I wonder if it is any setting related issue that deallocate an IP after a time later or it could be something to do with the hardware interface?

I don't have any setting about `eth0` on `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

EDIT: I use Ubuntu 12.04 and it does not have the network manager. It has WICD that handles the WiFi interface.

Comment: What OS are you talking about? Is there a network-manager-type service running (`NetworkManager` or `wicd`)?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: WICD is certainly a network-manager-type service. ["Wicd is an open source wired and wireless network manager for Linux"](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/) Try disabling it *completely* (try `/etc/init.d/wicd stop` or something like that) and see if the problem persists. If it does not, WICD is doing something to your interface and you should go over its configuration with a fine-toothed comb.